# PayPal Express FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME instead of SHIPTONAME

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express, shipping-address

In Magento 1.9 PayPal is transferring a *SHIPTONAME* which is used for the shipping address. Instead of populating firstname and lastname with the correct variables, only firstname is populated with *SHIPTONAME* which includes both first- and lastname and the field for lastname remains empty.
I need to change this so *SHIPTONAME* isn't being used and instead each field is populated with the correct variable.

This function

```
protected function _exportAddressses($data)
{
    $address = new Varien_Object();
    Varien_Object_Mapper::accumulateByMap($data, $address, $this->_billingAddressMap);
    $address->setExportedKeys(array_values($this->_billingAddressMap));
    $this->_applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds($address);
    $this->setExportedBillingAddress($address);
    // assume there is shipping address if there is at least one field specific to shipping
    if (isset($data['SHIPTONAME'])) {
        $shippingAddress = clone $address;
        Varien_Object_Mapper::accumulateByMap($data, $shippingAddress, $this->_shippingAddressMap);
        $this->_applyStreetAndRegionWorkarounds($shippingAddress);
        // PayPal doesn't provide detailed shipping name fields, so the name will be overwritten
        $shippingAddress->addData(array(
            'firstname'  => $data['SHIPTONAME'],
        ));
        $this->setExportedShippingAddress($shippingAddress);
    }
}
```

assigns *SHIPTONAME* to the firstname field, but simply adding a second declaration like `'lastname'  => $data['LASTNAME'],` has no effect, as apparently only the firstname field is being used for the shipping address for PayPal Express orders.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Model/Express/Checkout.php the *returnFromPaypal($token)* function includes this:

```
$shippingAddress->setLastname(null);
```

If I remove this, I can change the *_exportAddressses* function in Model/Api/Nvp.php to include

```
'firstname'  => $data['FIRSTNAME'],
'lastname'  => $data['LASTNAME'],
```

instead of

```
'firstname'  => $data['SHIPTONAME'],
```

This will properly assign first- and lastname to their respective fields.
I am still trying to figure out, why Magento is assigning the full name to the firstname field in the first place - and why nobody is bothered by this...

**Edit 26.09.2017**

As some have pointed out, this will force customers to use the billing address stored within PayPal without being able to select a differing shipping address. So I have chosen a different approach:

*Model/Api/Nvp.php*

```
$shiptofirstname = substr($data['SHIPTONAME'], 0, strrpos($data['SHIPTONAME'], ' '));
$shiptolastname = array_pop(explode(' ', $data['SHIPTONAME']));
$shippingAddress->addData(array(
    'firstname'  => $shiptofirstname,
    'lastname'  => $shiptolastname,
));
```

This will split SHIPTONAME after the last space. For my country this will most likely work 99% of the time as surnames usually don't include spaces. And even if the surname includes a space, at least I am not getting empty surname fields or double surnames (see a differenet solution further down) which will force me to edit orders manually but *only* incorrectly splitted surnames.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that `$data['FIRSTNAME']` and `$data['LASTNAME']` keeps data from Magento. This mean if shipping address name from PayPal is different from Magento it will be overwritten. I'm afraid the only solution here is to parse `$data['SHIPTONAME']`.

Comment: Correction, `$data['FIRSTNAME']` and `$data['LASTNAME']` is PayPal account holder which can definitely be different from shipping address name.

Comment: 2017 and we still ahve this problem ;) Is there a workaround or fix for this??? Or is the solution still to parse $data['SHIPTONAME']? thanks in advance

Comment: Update! I am an Magento 1934 .... if I take a look in the sales_flat_quote table ... then I can clearly see first+lastname ... can it be that the PP Exress was updated and is now sending firstname + lastname? only Magento keeps hard-resetting it? See here: http://imgur.com/a/ucf6U -- how else could it get there?

Comment: We are using this answer and see: the billing address has a firstname+lastname and the shipping address has a firstname+lastname .... only the account itself in customer/accoount in the backend nass *no value* for firstname+lastname. Is this fixed supposed to fix this too? Or is there another solution? thx

Answer (score 1):

Uncomment the SetName methods ... they are no longer needed.

Paypal *does* send the customer information Firstname and Lastname.

Magento 1934 28-8-17

```
public function returnFromPaypal($token)
{
    $this->_getApi();
    $this->_api->setToken($token)
        ->callGetExpressCheckoutDetails();
    $quote = $this->_quote;

    $this->_ignoreAddressValidation();

    // import shipping address
    $exportedShippingAddress = $this->_api->getExportedShippingAddress();
    if (!$quote->getIsVirtual()) {
        $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress();
        if ($shippingAddress) {
            if ($exportedShippingAddress) {
                $this->_setExportedAddressData($shippingAddress, $exportedShippingAddress);

                if ($quote->getPayment()->getAdditionalInformation(self::PAYMENT_INFO_BUTTON) == 1) {
                    // PayPal doesn't provide detailed shipping info: prefix, middlename, lastname, suffix
                    //$shippingAddress->setPrefix(null);
                    //$shippingAddress->setMiddlename(null);
                    //$shippingAddress->setLastname(null);
                    //$shippingAddress->setSuffix(null);
                }
```

Comment: So what's happening with this solution is SHIPTONAME will still insert the entire Pay Pal name into Magentos first name field while the described changes will result in the Pay Pal billing last name being inserted into Magentos last name field. Not a solution either I am afraid

Answer (score 0):

```
        // PayPal doesn't provide detailed shipping name fields, so the name will be overwritten
        $_arraydata = explode(' ', $data['SHIPTONAME'], 2);
        if (!empty($_arraydata[0]) && !empty($_arraydata[1])) {
            $shippingAddress->addData(array(
                'firstname'  => $_arraydata[0],
                'lastname'  => $_arraydata[1]
            ));
        } else {
            $shippingAddress->addData(array(
                'firstname'  => $data['FIRSTNAME'],
                'lastname'  => $data['LASTNAME']
            ));
        }
```