# PayPal Express Checkout saves address as default address saved in PayPal account

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal-express, onestepcheckout

We are currently on Magento 1.9.0.1 and using Onestepcheckout 4.0.10

When a customer logins on OneStepCheckout page and uses the Paypal Express checkout option, the billing and shipping default to the one saved in their Paypal account. This only happens for customers logging in, however users transacting as guest end up placing the order with no hiccups.

I've read a lot of answers on SO saying we need to 0 the **address_override** in Paypal extension however that hasn't helped at all. I even tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12033428/magento-paypal-is-taking-shipping-address-as-default-instead-of-billing-address) but it didn't really help.

Comment: Please check the next answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99884/paypal-express-firstname-and-lastname-instead-of-shiptoname