# PayPal Express Firstname and Lastname Empty: how to SET these fields using a query

Tags: magento-1.9, database, customer-account, paypal-express

We were having this issue

[PayPal Express FIRSTNAME and LASTNAME instead of SHIPTONAME](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/99884/paypal-express-firstname-and-lastname-instead-of-shiptoname)

Now we have many accounts where there is no firstname and secondlastname, however shipping data is correctly entered

How can we update the DB and fix these Empty `firstname and secondlastname` issues using the data available in billing or shipping address fields?

thx

Comment: What Magento version do you use, 1.9? What data do you want to update exactly? The customer firtsname / lastname in customer accounts or are also orders affected?

Comment: Accounts that are created

Answer (score 1):

Based on your very brief description of your situation I assume that ALL orders have the columns `customer_firstname` and `customer_lastname` in `sales_flat_order`filled correctly. Otherwise
those fields must be updated first from `sales_flat_order_address`. If that's necessary I can provide you a statement for that too.

With that given we have two possible situations (which matches for you can't be known from what you have posted in your question): There are entries for your customer accounts in the `customer_entity_varchar` table with NULL or empty value. In this case we need to update
those rows. The first two statements are for this situation. The second situation is that you don't have any entry at all for `firstname` or `lastname` in the `customer_entity_varchar` table. In this case we need to insert the data.
Please note that if you have more orders for one customer_id and different names (what technically can happen) the first matching data will be taken.

Feel free to use this statements. I would recommend you to test them first in an appropriate test / stage system since I don't know your customizations. On standard 1.9 Magento they work.

```
-- update customer firstname if there is a null entry in the varchar table
update customer_entity_varchar firstname
join sales_flat_order o on firstname.entity_id = o.customer_id and firstname.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'firstname' and entity_type_id = 1)
set firstname.value = o.customer_firstname
where firstname.value is NULL OR firstname.value = '';

-- update customer lastname if there is a null entry in the varchar table
update customer_entity_varchar lastname
join sales_flat_order o on lastname.entity_id = o.customer_id and lastname.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'lastname' and entity_type_id = 1)
set lastname.value = o.customer_lastname
where lastname.value is NULL OR lastname.value = '';


-- insert customer firstname values in varchar tables if there is no data at all for the customer that table
insert into customer_entity_varchar 
(entity_type_id , attribute_id, entity_id, value)
select 1, (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'firstname' and entity_type_id = 1), o.customer_id, o.customer_firstname
from
(select customer_id, customer_firstname from sales_flat_order group by customer_id) o 
join customer_entity c on c.entity_id = o.customer_id
left outer join customer_entity_varchar firstname on firstname.entity_id =  c.entity_id and firstname.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'firstname' and entity_type_id = 1)
where firstname.value is null;

-- insert customer lastname values in varchar tables if there is no data at all for the customer that table
insert into customer_entity_varchar 
(entity_type_id , attribute_id, entity_id, value)
select 1, (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'lastname' and entity_type_id = 1), o.customer_id, o.customer_firstname
from
(select customer_id, customer_firstname from sales_flat_order group by customer_id) o 
join customer_entity c on c.entity_id = o.customer_id
left outer join customer_entity_varchar lastname on lastname.entity_id =  c.entity_id and lastname.attribute_id = (select attribute_id from eav_attribute where attribute_code = 'lastname' and entity_type_id = 1)
where lastname.value is null;
```

And it would really be great, if you vote on / accept answers for the questions you ask - that's the way how others can also take profit from what we are donig here. But you are anyway welcome :-)